# Error evaluating function `min`: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context') ag-grid react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Error while importing ag -grid css file

```js
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css
```

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


  --ag-internal-padded-row-height: calc(var(--ag-row-height) - var(--ag-row-border-width));
  height: min(var(--ag-internal-calculated-line-height), var(--ag-internal-padded-row-height));
        ^
Error evaluating function `min`: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')
      Error in /Users/naveenkumarmd/Desktop/my-product/webui/node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css (line 2400, column 10)
 @ ./node_modules/ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css 2:26-111
 @ ./src/modules/apps/pages/app-list/components/app-list/data-table/data-table.jsx 10:0-46
 @ ./src/modules/apps/pages/app-list/app-list-page.jsx 19:0-98 196:56-65
 @ ./src/modules/apps/pages/app-list/index.js 1:0-42 1:0-42
 @ ./src/modules/apps/router.jsx 10:0-43 102:13-24
 @ ./src/modules/rootRouter.jsx 4:0-42 16:177-186
 @ ./react-app.js 3:0-48 7:38-48
 @ ./react-start.js 2:0-35 6:103-111
 @ ./index.js 18:0-23
```

React version : 18
StrictMode  :On

node version : 18.14.3

- **AG Grid version:**

```json
    "ag-grid-community": "^30.0.5",
    "ag-grid-react": "^30.0.5",
```

Tried

1. installing the package with --save,
2. Moved the import line to top and even bottom everywhere.

Comment: Happened because of using a lower version of "less" package.Solved it by upgrading the package.